# Decode struct with generic array property

Tags: swift, generics, decodable

I have a following struct with generics for API response with pagination:

```
struct Paginable<Body> {
    let data: [Body]
    let meta: Meta
}

extension Paginable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let pagination: Pagination

        struct Pagination: Codable {
            let total: Int
            let count: Int
            let perPage: Int
            let currentPage: Int
            let totalPages: Int
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to decode it like so:

```
let response  = try? response.decode(to: Paginable<Segment>.self)
```

So here's my attempt to make it `Decodable`:

```
extension Paginable where Body == Data {
    func decode<BodyType: Decodable>(to type: BodyType.Type) throws -> Paginable<BodyType> {
        guard let decodedJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BodyType.self, from: data) else {
            throw APIError.decodingFailure
        }

        return Paginable<BodyType>(data: decodedJSON, meta: self.meta)
    }
}
```

This gives me two errors:

1. > Cannot convert value of type 'Paginable.Meta' to expected argument type 'Paginable<_>.Meta'

on the line with `return` statement

If I change the meta property to some primitive type like Int, the error disappears. But Meta itself is `Codable`, so what's to problem here?

2. > Cannot convert value of type '[Data]' to expected argument type 'Data'

on the line with `guard` statement

How to solve this one?

Comment: Add the definition of `Segment`. Also the `JSON` that you're trying to decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conform `Paginable` to `Codable` like,

```
struct Paginable<Body>: Codable where Body: Codable {
    let data: [Body]
    let meta: Meta
}
```

Change `decode(data:to:)` method in `extension Paginable` to,

```
extension Paginable {
    static func decode<BodyType: Decodable>(data: Data, to type: BodyType.Type) throws -> BodyType? {
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BodyType.self, from: data)
            return response
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let response = try Paginable<Segment>.decode(data: data, to: Paginable<Segment>.self)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

`JSON` format:

```
{
  "data": [
      {
        "name": "Name-1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Name-2"
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "pagination": {
        "total": 100,
        "count": 10,
        "perPage": 5,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalPages": 10
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The data: [Body] part works! How can I return also the Meta?

Comment: I've added a sample JSON response for which the above code is working. See if you're getting anything other than that.

Comment: Aah, my bad, got Meta as well. Thank you! The JSON is correct(sorry for not including it).